# Hotkey to switch between Mac and PC using KVM

Tags: windows-7, macos, kvm-switch

I am using a [KVM Switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000L4D42Q) to use a mac external [keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V07N9U) for a Macbook Pro and a Dell laptop. The manual of the KVM switch says that I need the `Scroll lock` key as the hotkey to switch between the two systems. But since my Mac external keyboard doesn't have a `scroll lock` key, I [figured out](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-26398.html) that the `Clear` key on the numeric keypad would do the switching from Windows to Mac. But it is not working for switching from Mac to Windows. Has anyone encountered this situation? How to solve this. Is there any way to assign some key to the scroll key or fake a scroll lock key press to the kvm switch

Answer (score 1):

Check your KVM Switch install manual, there should be a way for you to configure a custom hot-key combination.  I have a IOGEAR KVM to switch between MBP and PC and had to do the same.